# Get 0-255 values from DataBufferByte.getData for each color

Tags: java, image-processing, arrays

I'm trying to analyze a pixel with the following code

```
    BufferedImage image;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    final byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte)         
    image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();final int pixelLength = 4;
        for (int pixel = 0, row = 0, col = 0; pixel < pixels.length; pixel += pixelLength) {
            byte alpha = pixels[pixel];
            byte blue = pixels[pixel + 1];
            byte green = pixels[pixel + 2];
            byte red = pixels[pixel + 3];
            //analyze colors
            col++;
            if (col == width) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }
        }
```

Im the most simple example I have an image with two pixels, one with transparency and one without.

Pixel 1: Red with transparency

```
HEX: FF0000, Alpha 140, (RGB: 255, 0, 0)
```

Pixel 2: Turquoise without transparency

```
HEX: 7FFFD8, Aplha  255, (RGB: 127, 255, 216)
```

The pixels array above has the following values: `[-116, 0, 0, -1, -1, -40, -1, 127]`
where each pixel has four bytes in the order of a, b, g, r (I think).

So my question is, how do I get from the result above to 0-255 values that Im used of :)

Comment: The byte structure is unsigned, so if you read values into it (as in the example you posted) the values will be in the range 0..255. Make sure each subpixel is indeed one Byte and not 2Bs or a float though. You might have a mistake in your printout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the question... but here is a simply answer based on my understanding.

Without going into a discussion of [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), you can go through the whole array and convert it using the following rule:

- if the value is less than zero, add 256
- if the value is zero or more, leave as is

Does this help?

Comment: Yes this helped, but I needed to change the type to something else than byte since (byte)-1 + 256 = -1

Comment: Sorry, I should have told you to use an int.